# APIGateway Proxy resource doesn't get path parameter into Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, proxy, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I need to create an API endpoint, which will trigger a Lambda function and return an image from an S3 bucket.

Example URL: https://abc.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/xyz/00/01/23911414.jpeg

I created an APIGateway instance manually using the web console and it’s working fine.
And I created the same (I guess) using CloudFormation and it’s not working.

**The Lambda gets triggered**, but it doesn't get the `path` parameter in the `event`.

But I want the Lambda function to get `/xyz/00/01/23911414.jpeg` as the `event['path']`.

Here is a part of my CloudFormation Template:

```
RestApi:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  Properties:
    Description: Example API Gateway
    EndpointConfiguration:
      Types:
        - REGIONAL
    Name: imaginary-api

ProxyResource:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
    ParentId: !GetAtt
      - RestApi
      - RootResourceId
    PathPart: '{proxy+}'

ProxyResourceANY:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
    ResourceId: !Ref ProxyResource
    HttpMethod: ANY
    AuthorizationType: NONE
    MethodResponses:
      - StatusCode: 200
    Integration:
      Type: AWS
      IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
      Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${ImaginaryLambda.Arn}/invocations
      Credentials: !GetAtt ApiGatewayIamRole.Arn
      PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
      RequestTemplates:
        "image/jpeg": ""
        "image/jpg": ""
      IntegrationResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200

RestAPIDeployment:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
  DependsOn:
    - ProxyResource
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
    StageName: dev

ImaginaryInvoke:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    FunctionName: !GetAtt ImaginaryLambda.Arn
    Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
    SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:abc/dev
```

This is the first time I'm using APIGateway and I might have done something wrong here. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

Adding `RequestParameters` to the Method won't work either.

```
RequestParameters:
  method.request.path.proxy: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You have [different possible integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-integration-types.html):

- aws (requires data mapping)
- aws_proxy
- mock
- http
- http_proxy

The AWS integration type requires data mapping to get the required attributes (check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html).

You can use AWS_PROXY to get the complete event (check: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) including the path attribute.

You can return binary file (be careful with content length) or return a s3 presigned url (thru a redirection for example).

Comment: Thanks. I tried AWS_PROXY, but it behaves the same. The manual one I created has AWS though.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question.
I was able to fix this with the following values.

```
RestApi:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  Properties:
    Description: Example API Gateway
    BinaryMediaTypes:
      - "*/*"              # <-- Important
    EndpointConfiguration:
      Types:
        - REGIONAL
    Name: imaginary-api

  ProxyResourceANY:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    DependsOn:
      ProxyResource
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
      ResourceId: !Ref ProxyResource
      HttpMethod: ANY
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.path.proxy: true  # <-- Important
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY  # <-- Important
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        ContentHandling: CONVERT_TO_TEXT  # <-- Important, depends on your code
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${ImaginaryLambda.Arn}/invocations
        Credentials: !GetAtt ApiGatewayIamRole.Arn
```

Something strange I noticed is, even though the manually created one showed as `AWS` in the web console, it showed as `AWS_PROXY` when I exported the stage as a Swagger definition.
Comparing the two Swagger definitions helped me a lot comparing the YAMLs taken out from **Export as Swagger + API Gateway Extensions** option.